# What will happen if I substitute beef liver for pork liver in sausage?

Tags: sausages, charcuterie

When we bought our cow this year, we opted to take all the organ meat. So, I now have a bunch of beef liver, I don't actually like beef liver cooked with onions or any other preparation I've encountered.  I do however like liverwurst, and braunschweiger.  Both of these sausages are traditional made with pork liver. I've never encountered pork liver in any other form though, so I don't know how it tastes by comparison.

Are the two livers roughly itnterchangable in other ways?  Fat content, texture, etc.
How do they compare flavor wise?
Am I doomed if I try and make sausage out of beef liver?

Comment: Last time I had pork liver I was a kid, but I remember it being strong flavored (compared to the beef liver with onions I occasionally still eat).  If it's any inspiration, the Braunschweiger sausage is sometimes made with just beef liver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at least here in germany it really is common to make liverwurst with beef liver (or more often and expensive: calf liver). So go ahead - you really won't regret it! Taken the percentage of actual liver in liverwurst you won't taste any difference, though I'd say beef liver tastes better.

Answer (score 1):

The classic Jewish chopped liver is (obviously) not made with pork liver. And it is *delicious*. I would be confident subbing beef liver into any pate or sausage preparation.